# Can s3fs mount different bucket and different account simultaneously?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mount, s3fs

Can s3fs mount different buckets with different account simultaneously so that I can transfer A account bucket’s folder to B account bucket?

Please told me how to do that.
Or having another way to achieve my needs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

s3fs can only mount one bucket/mountpoint at a time.  However you can mount two buckets simultaneously with separate credentials via:

```
s3fs -o passwd_file=/path/to/creds1 bucket1 mnt1
s3fs -o passwd_file=/path/to/creds2 bucket2 mnt2
```

There are some other variations if you want to store multiple credentials in the same passwd or AWS config file; see `man s3fs` for more information.